# Line string label text letters overlapping in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, labeling, linestring

I have a Map in OpenLayers 8.1.0 with a VectorLayer, containing a single LineString feature with a Text label. The line is a curve following the Great Circle with 100 vertices.

At certain zoom levels, the label displays correctly, whilst at other levels, the letters overlap each other.  I can't find any reference to this issue anywhere, nor deduce logic to predict the behaviour.

[image] [image] [image] [image]

My Text configuration is as follows:

```
const label = new Text({
        text: feature.get("name"),
        font: "1em sans-serif",
        fill: new Fill({ color: "#444444" }),
        stroke: new Stroke({ color: "#ffffff", width: 1 }),
        placement: "line",
        overflow: true,
    });
```

Any ideas, or directions for further investigation?

Comment: That's quite common on lines that are not perfectly straight, but it look like your line is a straight line between two points, so that is quite odd.  Just to be sure... how many vertices are actually on that line?  Is it just the two (start and end points)?

Comment: Does this happen on multiple devices with different browsers?  It might be a device specific problem with browser using hardware acceleration.  Try turning that off in browser settings.

Comment: @SonofaBeach, Ahhh, the line is actually a curve along the Great Circle with 100 vertices (edited the question to add this detail).  The curve just isn't noticeable at that short distance.  Any tips to deal with it?

Comment: As per @TomazicM post below, you can configure a different geometry for the label other than the geometry of the line itself.  May be worth a shot.  I do something like this in my OpenLayers app using an automatically "simplified" version of the line's geometry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution for this particular case would be to use style function where new two point line string geometry is created in the middle of the original line string, with screen length approximately the same as label length. Label style is then applied with this geometry.

Code below is just proof of concept that this can work, it's in no way bullet proof ( turf.js library is used for geometry calculations):

```
var geoJSONFormat = new ol.format.GeoJSON();

function featureToGeoJSON(feature) {
  var geoJSON = geoJSONFormat.writeFeatureObject(feature, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326'
  });
  return(geoJSON);
}

function geoJSONToFeature(geoJSON) {
  var feature = geoJSONFormat.readFeature(geoJSON, {
    dataProjection:'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  });
  return(feature);
}

var start = turf.point([150, -33]);
var end = turf.point([147, -42]);

var greatCircle = turf.greatCircle(start, end);
var greatCircleFeature = geoJSONToFeature(greatCircle);

const label = new ol.style.Text({
  font: "1em sans-serif",
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: "#444444" }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "#ffffff", width: 1 }),
  placement: 'line',
  overflow: true,
});

var lineStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    width: 2,
    color: '#0000FF'
  })
});

var labelStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  text: label
});

function greatCircleStyle(feature, resolution) {
  const geojson = featureToGeoJSON(feature);
  
  const len = turf.length(geojson);
  const lineLenPixels = len * 1000 / resolution;
  const textLenPixels = 60;
  const nDiv = Math.trunc(lineLenPixels / textLenPixels / 2) * 2 + 1 ;
  const nDiv1 = (nDiv - 1) / 2;
  const nDiv2 = nDiv1 + 1;
  
  const pointCoord1 = turf.getCoord(turf.along(geojson, len / nDiv * nDiv1));
  const pointCoord2 = turf.getCoord(turf.along(geojson, len / nDiv * nDiv2));
  const line = turf.lineString([pointCoord1, pointCoord2]);
  const lineFeature = geoJSONToFeature(line);
  
  labelStyle.getText().setText(len.toLocaleString(undefined, {maximumFractionDigits: 0}) + ' km');
  labelStyle.setGeometry(lineFeature.getGeometry());
  
  return([lineStyle, labelStyle]);
}

var greatCircleLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [greatCircleFeature]
  }),
  style: greatCircleStyle
});
```

Here are a few examples at different zooms:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a very clever approach.  I've implemented something along these lines, and all is working as expected.  Thank-you.